# Allegro 4 wait for user input

Tags: c++, switch-statement, user-input, wait, allegro

I can't figure out how to get allegro to wait for the user to press a key. I assumed readkey() waited because it stopped my timer, which I have since removed. So far I have learned if I use if(key[KEY_1]) the program will only work when the key is held down.

The below is my game loop. Right now it draws everything and stops on the last question. It goes for the default in the switch and increments score to -10. I don't know how to get it to wait. I tried clear keybuff because I thought if the buffer was clear then it would have to wait for a key. Nope.

I can only use allegro 4, I can't use allegro 5.

```
        while (!key [KEY_Q])
        {
            blit(back, buffer, 100, 75, 100, 75, 180, 20);
           textout_ex(buffer, Narial14, "PRESS Q TO QUIT",100,75, WHITE,-1);

            //add a score
           int score =0;
           Question* run[10] =      
           {ch1q1,ch1q2,ch1q3,ch1q4,ch1q5,ch1q6,ch1q7,ch1q8,ch1q9,ch1q10};          
        for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
        {
            clear_keybuf();
            run[i]->draw(); 
            int val;
            val = readkey();

                switch (val)
                {

                    case 0:
                        if(run[i]->getAnswer())
                        score ++;
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        if(KEY_S)
                    break;

                    default:
                        score--;
                        break;
                }
            blit(back, buffer, 320-70, 400, 320-70, 400, 130, 30);
            textprintf_centre_ex(buffer,font,320,410,WHITE,-1,
            "SCORE %d", score);
```